# Парсинг HTML файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

у меня есть html документ, в котором записаны результаты матчей по теннису.
Из данного html документа мне нужно получить названия лиг и имена игроков, которые играют в данной лиге.
Проблема в том, что названия лиг и информация по матчам находятся в отдельных блоках html кода.
Ожидаемый результат вывода:

```
------------------------
ATP - ОДИНОЧНЫЙ РАЗРЯД
------------------------
Тиафо Ф. (Сша)
Бублик А. (Каз)
------------------------
ATP - ОДИНОЧНЫЙ РАЗРЯД
------------------------
Эдмунд К. (Вел)
Харрис Дж. (Южн)
------------------------
ITF - ОДИНОЧНЫЙ РАЗРЯД
------------------------
```

и т.д. ....

То есть мне нужно каждой паре игроков присвоить их родительскую лигу и так выводить с каждой парой игроков

Вот мой код, в нем все выводится по отдельности, сначала в цикле выводятся лиги, потом имена игроков:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import codecs

f = codecs.open("html_score.html", 'r', 'utf-8') # читаем код html из файла
html = f.read() # записываем его в переменную 

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

list_matchs = soup.find_all("div", {"title":"Подробности матча!"}) # получаем все матчи
list_ligs = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"event__header"}) # получаем все родительские лиги матчей

# Перебор родительских лиг
for ligs in list_ligs:

    name_lig = ligs.find("span", {"class":"event__title--type"}) # получаем название лиги 

    print(name_lig.text)

# Перебор матчей
for match in list_matchs:

    name_player = match.find_all("div", {"class":"event__participant"}) # получаем название матча
    name_player_one = name_player[0].text
    name_player_two = name_player[1].text

    print(name_player_one)
    print(name_player_two)
```

Данные берутся из общей папки, из документа html. Я не нашел каких-то зависимостей между лигами и матчами, по-этому не знаю, как решить данную проблему.
Прошу помощи с кодом =) Очень хочется разобраться, как можно решить данную задачу.

Вот тот самый `HTML`:

```html
<div class="sportName tennis">
  <div class="event__header">
    <div class="event__check"></div>
    <div class="icon--flag event__title fl_3473162">
      <div class="event__titleBox"><span class="event__title--type">ATP - ОДИНОЧНЫЙ РАЗРЯД</span><span class="event__title--name" title="Вашингтон (США), хард">Вашингтон (США), хард</span></div><span class="toggleMyLeague 2_9011_rgTHIK74"></span>
    </div><a href="#" class="event__info active">Сетка</a>
    <div class="event__expander icon--expander collapse" title="Скрыть все игры этого турнира!"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="g_2_4QWoo2eA" title="Подробности матча!" class="event__match event__match--twoLine">
    <div class="event__check"></div>
    <div class="event__stage">Завершен</div>
    <div class="event__participant event__participant--home fontBold">Тиафо Ф. (Сша)</div>
    <div class="event__participant event__participant--away">Бублик А. (Каз)</div>
    <div class="event__score event__score--home">2</div>
    <div class="event__score event__score--away">0</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--1">6</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--1">1</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--2">7<sup class="event__part--ex">7</sup></div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--2">6<sup class="event__part--ex">5</sup></div>
  </div>
  <div id="g_2_jBAbIc3G" title="Подробности матча!" class="event__match event__match--twoLine">
    <div class="event__check"></div>
    <div class="event__stage">Завершен</div>
    <div class="event__participant event__participant--home fontBold">Эдмунд К. (Вел)</div>
    <div class="event__participant event__participant--away">Харрис Дж. (Южн)</div>
    <div class="event__score event__score--home">2</div>
    <div class="event__score event__score--away">0</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--1">6</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--1">1</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--2">6</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--2">4</div>
  </div>
  <div id="g_2_dpTOvnbg" title="Подробности матча!" class="event__match event__match--twoLine">
    <div class="event__check"></div>
    <div class="event__stage">Завершен</div>
    <div class="event__participant event__participant--home">Рублёв А. (Рос)</div>
    <div class="event__participant event__participant--away fontBold">Гоёвчик П. (Гер)</div>
    <div class="event__score event__score--home">1</div>
    <div class="event__score event__score--away">2</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--1">6<sup class="event__part--ex">6</sup></div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--1">7<sup class="event__part--ex">8</sup></div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--2">6</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--2">4</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--3">6<sup class="event__part--ex">2</sup></div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--3">7<sup class="event__part--ex">7</sup></div>
  </div>
  <div id="g_2_0G2PXiLg" title="Подробности матча!" class="event__match event__match--twoLine">
    <div class="event__check"></div>
    <div class="event__stage">Завершен</div>
    <div class="event__participant event__participant--home fontBold">Цонга Ж. (Фра)</div>
    <div class="event__participant event__participant--away">Хачанов К. (Рос)</div>
    <div class="event__score event__score--home">2</div>
    <div class="event__score event__score--away">1</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--1">6</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--1">4</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--2">2</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--2">6</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--3">7</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--3">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="event__header">
    <div class="event__check"></div>
    <div class="icon--flag event__title fl_3473162">
      <div class="event__titleBox"><span class="event__title--type">ITF - ОДИНОЧНЫЙ РАЗРЯД</span><span class="event__title--name" title="Китцбюэль (Австрия), грунт">Китцбюэль (Австрия), грунт</span>
      </div><span class="toggleMyLeague 2_9011_84SxvsCb"></span>
    </div><a href="#" class="event__info active">Сетка</a>
    <div class="event__expander icon--expander collapse" title="Скрыть все игры этого турнира!"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="g_2_CQt8DEGe" title="Подробности матча!" class="event__match event__match--twoLine">
    <div class="event__check"></div>
    <div class="event__stage">Завершен</div>
    <div class="event__participant event__participant--home fontBold">Шарди Ж. (Фра)</div>
    <div class="event__participant event__participant--away">Лайович Д. (Сер)</div>
    <div class="event__score event__score--home">2</div>
    <div class="event__score event__score--away">1</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--1">3</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--1">6</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--2">6</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--2">4</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--3">6</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--3">3</div>
  </div>
  <div id="g_2_vemj9V4F" title="Подробности матча!" class="event__match event__match--twoLine">
    <div class="event__check"></div>
    <div class="event__stage">Завершен</div>
    <div class="event__participant event__participant--home fontBold">Рууд К. (Нор)</div>
    <div class="event__participant event__participant--away">Бахингер М. (Гер)</div>
    <div class="event__score event__score--home">2</div>
    <div class="event__score event__score--away">0</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--1">6</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--1">4</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--2">7<sup class="event__part--ex">7</sup></div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--2">6<sup class="event__part--ex">3</sup></div>
  </div>
  <div id="g_2_biQ8fzxI" title="Подробности матча!" class="event__match event__match--twoLine">
    <div class="event__check"></div>
    <div class="event__stage">Завершен</div>
    <div class="event__participant event__participant--home fontBold">Рамос А. (Исп)</div>
    <div class="event__participant event__participant--away">Муньяр Х. (Исп)</div>
    <div class="event__score event__score--home">2</div>
    <div class="event__score event__score--away">0</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--1">6</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--1">2</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--2">6</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--2">3</div>
  </div>
  <div id="g_2_C6xo8uB5" title="Подробности матча!" class="event__match event__match--twoLine">
    <div class="event__check"></div>
    <div class="event__stage">Завершен</div>
    <div class="event__participant event__participant--home">Новак Д. (Авт)</div>
    <div class="event__participant event__participant--away fontBold">Куэвас П. (Уру)</div>
    <div class="event__score event__score--home">1</div>
    <div class="event__score event__score--away">2</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--1">7<sup class="event__part--ex">7</sup></div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--1">6<sup class="event__part--ex">1</sup></div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--2">0</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--2">6</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--3">2</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--3">6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="event__header">
    <div class="event__check"></div>
    <div class="icon--flag event__title fl_3473162">
      <div class="event__titleBox"><span class="event__title--type">ЧЕЛЕНДЖЕР - ОДИНОЧНЫЙ РАЗРЯД</span><span class="event__title--name" title="Лос Кабос (Мексика), хард">Лос Кабос (Мексика), хард</span></div>
      <span class="toggleMyLeague 2_9011_88suDyRE"></span>
    </div><a href="#" class="event__info active">Сетка</a>
    <div class="event__expander icon--expander collapse" title="Скрыть все игры этого турнира!"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="g_2_pKU5M2Ya" title="Подробности матча!" class="event__match event__match--twoLine">
    <div class="event__check"></div>
    <div class="event__stage">Завершен</div>
    <div class="event__participant event__participant--home">Типсаревич Я. (Сер)</div>
    <div class="event__participant event__participant--away fontBold">Албот Р. (Мол)</div>
    <div class="event__score event__score--home">1</div>
    <div class="event__score event__score--away">2</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--1">5</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--1">7</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--2">6</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--2">2</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--3">0</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--3">6</div>
  </div>
  <div id="g_2_bqpBJ0II" title="Подробности матча!" class="event__match event__match--twoLine">
    <div class="event__check"></div>
    <div class="event__stage">Завершен</div>
    <div class="event__participant event__participant--home">Гарин К. (Чил)</div>
    <div class="event__participant event__participant--away fontBold">Лондеро Х. И. (Арг)</div>
    <div class="event__score event__score--home">1</div>
    <div class="event__score event__score--away">2</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--1">6</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--1">3</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--2">2</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--2">6</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--3">3</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--3">6</div>
  </div>
  <div id="g_2_6TV1NrJg" title="Подробности матча!" class="event__match event__match--twoLine">
    <div class="event__check"></div>
    <div class="event__stage">Завершен</div>
    <div class="event__participant event__participant--home fontBold">Дэниел Т. (Япо)</div>
    <div class="event__participant event__participant--away">Сандгрен Т. (Сша)</div>
    <div class="event__score event__score--home">2</div>
    <div class="event__score event__score--away">0</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--1">6</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--1">2</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--2">6</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--2">0</div>
  </div>
  <div class="event__header">
    <div class="event__check"></div>
    <div class="icon--flag event__title fl_3473164">
      <div class="event__titleBox"><span class="event__title--type">WTA - ОДИНОЧНЫЙ РАЗРЯД</span><span class="event__title--name" title="Вашингтон (США), хард">Вашингтон (США), хард</span></div><span class="toggleMyLeague 2_9012_xnxlobHB"></span>
    </div><a href="#" class="event__info active">Сетка</a>
    <div class="event__expander icon--expander collapse" title="Скрыть все игры этого турнира!"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="g_2_KIfatMzg" title="Подробности матча!" class="event__match event__match--twoLine">
    <div class="event__check"></div>
    <div class="event__stage">Завершен</div>
    <div class="event__participant event__participant--home fontBold">Дияс З. (Каз)</div>
    <div class="event__participant event__participant--away">Gauff C. (Сша)</div>
    <div class="event__score event__score--home">2</div>
    <div class="event__score event__score--away">0</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--1">6</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--1">4</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--2">6</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--2">2</div>
  </div>
  <div id="g_2_tSees2Ln" title="Подробности матча!" class="event__match event__match--twoLine">
    <div class="event__check"></div>
    <div class="event__stage">Завершен</div>
    <div class="event__participant event__participant--home">Викери С. (Сша)</div>
    <div class="event__participant event__participant--away fontBold">Джорджи К. (Ита)</div>
    <div class="event__score event__score--home">0</div>
    <div class="event__score event__score--away">2</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--1">2</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--1">6</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--2">5</div>
    <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--2">7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вот Вам **идея**: судя по html, нужно парсить информацию между тегами `<div class="event__titleBox">` (и не забыть два крайних случая - от начала до упомянутого тега, и от упомянутого тега до конца фрагмента, что парсится). Соответственно, не кидайтесь кодить, а напишите псевдо-код, алгоритм.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужные Вам элементы, а именно лига и её матчи, находятся на одном уровне в `DOM`.

Благодаря этому, их можно легко перебирать, используя метод `find_next_sibling`.
Данный метод возвращает следующий указанный элемент, находящийся на том же уровне.

Осталось лишь различить элементы, которые возвращаются методом, на принадлежность к лиге или матчу.
Это довольно легко сделать с помощью проверки атрибута `class`.

В итоге у меня получилась функция `parse`, которая возвращает список словарей вида:

```py
[
    {
        'league': 'ATP - ОДИНОЧНЫЙ РАЗРЯД',
        'participants': [
            'Тиафо Ф. (Сша)',
            'Бублик А. (Каз)'
        ]
    }, 
    {
        'league': 'WTA - ОДИНОЧНЫЙ РАЗРЯД',
        'participants': [
            'Викери С. (Сша)',
            'Джорджи К. (Ита)'
        ]
    }
]
```

***Код:***

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def parse(html: str) -> list:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    matches = []
    sibling = soup.find('div', {'class': 'event__header'})
    while sibling:
        if sibling['class'] == ['event__header']:
            title = sibling.find('span', {'class': 'event__title--type'}).getText()
        else:
            participant_1 = sibling.find('div', {'class': 'event__participant'})
            participant_2 = participant_1.find_next_sibling('div')
            matches.append({'league': title, 'participants': [participant_1.getText(), participant_2.getText()]})

        sibling = sibling.find_next_sibling('div')

    return matches


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('page.html', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        html = f.read()

    matches = parse(html)

    for match in matches:
        print(
            f"------------------------\n"
            f"{match['league']}\n"
            f"------------------------\n"
            f"{match['participants'][0]}\n"
            f"{match['participants'][1]}"
        )
```

***stdout:***

```html
------------------------
ATP - ОДИНОЧНЫЙ РАЗРЯД
------------------------
Тиафо Ф. (Сша)
Бублик А. (Каз)
------------------------
ATP - ОДИНОЧНЫЙ РАЗРЯД
------------------------
Эдмунд К. (Вел)
Харрис Дж. (Южн)
------------------------
ATP - ОДИНОЧНЫЙ РАЗРЯД
------------------------
Рублёв А. (Рос)
Гоёвчик П. (Гер)
------------------------
ATP - ОДИНОЧНЫЙ РАЗРЯД
------------------------
Цонга Ж. (Фра)
Хачанов К. (Рос)
------------------------
ITF - ОДИНОЧНЫЙ РАЗРЯД
------------------------
Шарди Ж. (Фра)
Лайович Д. (Сер)
------------------------
ITF - ОДИНОЧНЫЙ РАЗРЯД
------------------------
Рууд К. (Нор)
Бахингер М. (Гер)
------------------------
ITF - ОДИНОЧНЫЙ РАЗРЯД
------------------------
Рамос А. (Исп)
Муньяр Х. (Исп)
------------------------
ITF - ОДИНОЧНЫЙ РАЗРЯД
------------------------
Новак Д. (Авт)
Куэвас П. (Уру)
------------------------
ЧЕЛЕНДЖЕР - ОДИНОЧНЫЙ РАЗРЯД
------------------------
Типсаревич Я. (Сер)
Албот Р. (Мол)
------------------------
ЧЕЛЕНДЖЕР - ОДИНОЧНЫЙ РАЗРЯД
------------------------
Гарин К. (Чил)
Лондеро Х. И. (Арг)
------------------------
ЧЕЛЕНДЖЕР - ОДИНОЧНЫЙ РАЗРЯД
------------------------
Дэниел Т. (Япо)
Сандгрен Т. (Сша)
------------------------
WTA - ОДИНОЧНЫЙ РАЗРЯД
------------------------
Дияс З. (Каз)
Gauff C. (Сша)
------------------------
WTA - ОДИНОЧНЫЙ РАЗРЯД
------------------------
Викери С. (Сша)
Джорджи К. (Ита)
```